# How to change the post title tag in WordPress?

Tags: html, css, wordpress, custom-wordpress-pages, theme-customizer

WordPress post titles are usually in the h1 tag by default. How to write the post title inside the h2 tag?
[WordPress Post Title](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rNdhP.png)

I go through all the themes files but can not get any solution. When I Inspect the page, I find this A Comprehensive Guide to Holistic Health and Wholeness. Which means the page title is inside the named "entry-title". But I can not find such a class in the theme files. I need to modify the title tag and make it into h2 tag. Squaretype theme is used here.

Comment: I have explained in answer. Try that.

Answer (score 0):

You can render the **H2 tag** for title by passing parameters in **the_title()** function, like this:-

```
<?php the_title('<h2>','</h2>'); ?>
```

This is written in the [user contribution in the_title() function page](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/the_title/#user-contributed-notes) of WordPress documentation. I read it there.

Another way is to use **get_the_title() function**, it will just give the **title text**. And then you can **wrap it in the h2 element**. Here is the example:-

```
<h2><?php echo get_the_title(); ?></h2>
```

Comment: @Md.NafiulIslam If its not working, then use get_the_title() it will echo only the text. Then you can wrap it inside h2 element.

Answer (score 0):

Here you can find the post title in **single.php** file or **content-single.php** file just replace

```html
<?php the_title( '<h2 class="entry-title">', '</h2>' ); ?>
or
<h2><?php echo get_the_title(); ?></h2>
```